# Change css style of paper-icon-button in polymer 1.0 using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, polymer-1.0

I have used paper-icon-button in my page in the following way:

```html
<template is="dom-bind" id="t">  
  <paper-icon-button id="back" icon="arrow-back" style="display:{{displayArrow}}"  alt="arrow-back" title="arrow-back" on-click="onBackPress"></paper-icon-button>
</template>
```

Now, I want Java script to change the display value to 'none' or 'block' on certain condition.

My java script is:

```js
<script>
var template = document.querySelector('#t');
template.displayArrow='none';

</script>
```

This does not seem to work, as template.displayArrow is undefined. Please suggest

This is what my final code looks like:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test Home</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
  <style>
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="t">

   <paper-toolbar id="header">
    <paper-icon-button id="b" icon="arrow-back" style="display:{{displayArrow}}" alt="arrow-back" title="arrow-back" on-click="onBackPress"></paper-icon-button>
    
    <h3>TestPage</h3>
   </paper-toolbar>

   

  </template>

  <script>
   var template = document.querySelector('#t');
   template.displayArrow='none'
      
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`displayArrow` is a variable.

Below snippet will work for you

```
/* To hide the element */
document.getElementById("back").style.display = "none";

/* To show the element */
document.getElementById("back").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem is document.getElementById("back") gives me a null object.

Comment: It will give you null when you are trying to call the object before DOM is loaded. Put the javascript snippet at the end of code.

Comment: i am putting it at the end.

Comment: `paper-icon-button` has attribute `id="b"`. Either change the id in javascript code to `b` or change the attribute value to `back`. Have created a sample in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/samir_s/fvorbra1/1/

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. The issue with my code is most likely with the binding of the values and related to the polymer.